# Footer not sticky to bottom bootstrap 5.2.2

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I use Laravel Inertia Vue on my project and use bootstrap 5.2.2 in my depedencies.

After load the css to  tag, i want to make sticky footer. But i wonder why the footer is not sticky on the bottom.

I already try to find solution, and its still dont work after i apply the solution to my code.

My blade code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Website name" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/offcanvas.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  @inertia
</body>

</html>
```

My components layout page:

```
<template>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
           //Nav here
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="nav-scroller bg-body shadow-sm">
        <nav class="nav" aria-label="Secondary navigation">
            <span class="nav-link">Silakan pilih menu:</span>
            <Link class="nav-link" v-for="(menu, index) in menus" :key="index" :href="`/page/${menu.id}`">{{
        menu.name
            }} </Link>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <main class="flex-fill">
        <div class="container">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
        </div>
    </footer>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example where you got the code for the sticky footer, there is an external `css` file where the footer gets it's stickyness from. I have copied it and I will paste here(Inline CSS)

Change your blade code to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Website name" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/offcanvas.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <style>
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  @inertia
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help sir. I wonder why there is still have additional css for sticky footer